# Are there any packages similar to fncychap?

Tags: sectioning, packages, chapters, book-design, fncychap

I use `fncychap` this way:

```
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
```

This lets me have pretty decent chapters, ToC and title page design. But the options are scarce and too popular.

Are there any other packages I can use in the same way?

```
\usepackage[Otherstyle]{otherpack}
```

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know, there's no such ready to use package similar to `fncychap`. However, you have some possibilities:

The [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) document class has some predefined chapter styles (see Section **6.5 Chapter headings** of the manual). You can easily use one of those predefined styles or define your own (the manual has examples). If you want to use some of the predefined styles but don't want to use `memoir`, you can easily see how the styles were implemented and use this to implement them yourself (using the `titlesec` package, for example).

The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package lets you define your own styles (the package documentation has some examples).

The [`classicthesis`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) package also defines some styles; again, if you don't want to use the class, you can use the styles as an inspiration; the package defines the styles using the `titlesec` package, so you can easily see how the styles were defined.

**Vincent Zoonekynd** has in [`this page`](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) a collection of some styles and the code is available (thanks to **Thérèse** for helping me to find the link).

Some time ago **Stefan Kottwitz** designed a fancy chapter style using `TikZ` and `titlesec`; you can see it (code available) in his blog [`here`](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/).

**Lian Tze Lim** from the Malaysian LaTeX User Group has another fancy design (inspired on Stefan's) and you can see it [`here`](http://latex-my.blogspot.mx/2009/11/fancy-chapter-headings.html). The author provides links to the code. (Thanks to **rvf0068** for providing the link).

Personally, I don't like much the styles designed by `fncychap`.

Comment: I'm totally latex-naive so I like the fncychap and I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: Perhaps you’re thinking of http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html.

Comment: @Thérèse exactly that was the page! Thank you.

Comment: @JuanjoConti perhaps, if you have some design in mind, you could post an image and we could help you to implement it.

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina, I've no design in mind. I just wanted something simple that looks enough good :)

Comment: @JuanjoConti perhaps if you give a look at some of the styles I mentioned in my answer you can find something you like and we can help you to obtain it.

Comment: Here is also another fancy design http://latex-my.blogspot.mx/2009/11/fancy-chapter-headings.html

Comment: @rvf0068 I'll incorporate it to my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JuanjoConti I've added some more possibilities to my answer.