# Chapter styles catalog

Tags: sectioning, formatting

There are many questions in this forum regarding how to produce one or another chapter/section format. However, I can't find a comprehensive **catalog** of styles (examples with code), something like the [titlepages](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf) document of Peter Wilson. I am specially interested in book design. Of course, it will depend a great deal on the document class, but the idea is to have some reference (and source of inspiration, if you like).

Comment: You mean something like this: [Title pages](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_title/0.html), [Chapters](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html), [Sections](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html)

Comment: @Werner Precisely!

Comment: There is a little gallery in the memoir documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Vincent Zoonekynd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10931/vincent-zoonekynd) has accumulated a set of these for [Title pages](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_title/0.html), [Chapters](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) and [Sections](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html). The don't utilize any packages, so the code is visible for use and change as needed.

- Here is one sample for `\maketitle`:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \makeatletter
  \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1pt\hfill \kern \z@}
  \renewcommand{\maketitle}{\begin{titlepage}%
      \let\footnotesize\small
      \let\footnoterule\relax
      \parindent \z@
      \reset@font
      \null
      \vskip 10\p@
      \hbox{\mbox{%
          \hspace{4pt}%
          \fbox{\includegraphics[width=3em]{tiger}}%
          \hspace{4pt}
          }%
        \vrule depth 0.9\textheight%
        \mbox{\hspace{2em}}
        \vtop{% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
          \vskip 40\p@
          \begin{flushleft}
            \Large \@author \par
          \end{flushleft}
          \vskip 80\p@
          \begin{flushleft}
            \huge \bfseries \@title \par
          \end{flushleft}
          \vfil
          }}
      \null
    \end{titlepage}%
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  }

  \makeatother
  \author{Isidore Ducasse, Comte de Lautréamont}
  \author{Lautréamont}
  \title{Les Chants de Maldoror}
  \date{1874}
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \end{document}
  ```
- Here is [one sample](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/14.ps.gz) for `\chapter`s that modifies `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` in the usual way:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{report}
  \makeatletter
  \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
  \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
          \thickhrulefill\quad
          \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
          \quad \thickhrulefill
          \par\nobreak
          \vspace*{10\p@}%
          \interlinepenalty\@M
          \hrule
          \vspace*{10\p@}%
          \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
          \par
          \vspace*{10\p@}%
          \hrule
      %\vskip 40\p@
      \vskip 100\p@
    }}
  \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
          \thickhrulefill
          \par\nobreak
          \vspace*{10\p@}%
          \interlinepenalty\@M
          \hrule
          \vspace*{10\p@}%
          \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
          \par
          \vspace*{10\p@}%
          \hrule
      %\vskip 40\p@
      \vskip 100\p@
    }}
  \begin{document}
  \chapter{Introduction}
  \end{document}
  ```
- [Here is another](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/20.ps.gz) for `\section`s:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{lettrine,lipsum}
  \def\LettrineFontHook{\bfseries\sffamily\selectfont}
  \makeatletter
  \def\section{\@ifstar\unnumberedsection\numberedsection}
  \def\numberedsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
    \numberedsectionwithtwoarguments\numberedsectionwithoneargument}
  \def\unnumberedsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
    \unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments\unnumberedsectionwithoneargument}
  \def\numberedsectionwithoneargument#1{\numberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
  \def\unnumberedsectionwithoneargument#1{\unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
  \def\numberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
    \ifhmode\par\fi
    \removelastskip
    \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \lettrine[lines=2,slope=0pt,nindent=0pt]{{\thesection\hspace*{1mm}}}{}%
    \begingroup \bfseries #2.\  \endgroup
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
      \protect\numberline{\thesection}%
      #1}%
    }
  \def\unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
    \ifhmode\par\fi
    \removelastskip
    \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
  %  \refstepcounter{section}%
    \noindent
    \leavevmode
    \begingroup
    \bfseries
  %  \thesection\ 
    #2.\quad
    \endgroup
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
  %    \protect\numberline{\thesection}%
      #1}%
    }
  \makeatother
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section*{Introduction}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Suite}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Suite}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Fin}
  \lipsum[2]
  %\tableofcontents
  \end{document}
  ```

---

Specific to chapters, the [`memoir` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) also provides its [own set of chapter styles](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf). Appendix **B Showcases** of the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) highlights some of the styles:

- The `bianchi` chapter style:

  [image]
- The `dash` chapter style:

  [image]
- The `lyhne` chapter style:

  [image]

---

The [`fncychap` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fncychap) could also provide some inspiration for titles, although it's not used often.

- The `Lenny` chapter style:

  [image]
- The `Glenn` chapter style:

  [image]
- The `Conny` chapter style:

  [image]
- The `Rejne` chapter style:

  [image]

and so forth...

---

Peter Wilson has collected some [ideas in terms of title pages](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf) and how to create them. Here's one example:

[image]

---

On this site, consider reading the following posts:

- [Are there any packages similar to `fncychap`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67637/5764)
- [Customizing chapter style with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160320/5764)
- [How to customize chapter heading style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94729/5764)
- [Customizing chapter style in `scrbook`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150923/5764)
- [How to customize the table of contents using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19796/5764)
- [Chapter style: how to put a box on the edge like `veelo` style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195117/5764)